# Powerball number generator:

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want my output to be in increasing order, like:

Your numbers:  3 12 14 26 47     Powerball:  2
Your numbers:  1  4 31 34 51     Powerball: 17
Your numbers: 10 12 49 50 53     Powerball: 35

But my code give me something like this:

Ofical Powerball number generator
How many sets of numbers? 5
Your numbers: 41 29 13 43 15 Powerball: 29
Your numbers: 44 4 18 47 51 Powerball: 15
Your numbers: 24 7 39 28 47 Powerball: 19
Your numbers: 39 46 18 23 19 Powerball: 41
Your numbers: 49 21 47 37 1 Powerball: 8

```
import random
print "Ofical Powerball number generator"
x = int(raw_input("How many sets of numbers? "))
z = range(1,42)

for n in range(x):
  z1 = random.choice(z)
  i = random.sample(range(1,53), 5)
  q = i[0]
  w = i[1]
  e = i[2]
  r = i[3]
  t = i[4]
  print "Your numbers: " + str(q), str(w), str(e), str(r), str(t) +  " Powerball: "+ str(z1)
```

How do I get the last line in my code to display the numbers in an order?

Comment: By sorting your variables before you print them out. Personally, I'd use the [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pre-sort the assignment to `i`:

```
i = sorted(random.sample(range(1, 53), 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print 'Your numbers: ' + str(sorted(random.sample(range(1,53), 5))) + ' Powerball: ' + str(random.choice(z))
```

Answer (score 1):

I added in random seeding for each draw so that others running just the MersenneTwister are less likely to end up with the same picks.

```
import random
print "Powerball number generator"
x = int(raw_input("How many sets of numbers? "))

for i in range( x ):
  white = range( 1, 70 )
  n = [None] * 5
  for j in range( len(n) ):
    random.SystemRandom()
    n[j] = random.sample( white, 1 ).pop()
    white.remove( n[j] )

  n.sort()
  random.SystemRandom()
  powerball = random.choice( range( 1, 27 ) )
  print( "Your numbers: " ),
  for j in range( 5 ):
    print( str(n[j]).rjust(2) + " " ),
  print( "\tPowerball: "+ str(powerball) )
```